# XPATH help XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I need help getting the count of preceding parent elements for INVOICES_ROW.

The XML follows this set up:

```
<ROOT>
   <INVOICES>
      <INVOICES_ROW>
      </INVOICES_ROW>
   </INVOICES>
</ROOT>
```

The XPATH I am trying is:

```
<!-- Returns 2 for the first INVOICES_ROW and jumps to 4 for the next but then proceeds with incrementing by 1 anytime after. -->
count(preceding::*/ancestor::*/position())

<!-- Returns 1 for the first INVOICES_ROW and then jumps to 3 for the next one, but then proceeds with incrementing by 1. -->
count(preceding::*/parent::*/position())

<!-- Same thing happens with position() removed from either XPath Expression -->
```

Comment: Can you try explaining the problem once again. Do you want the ancestors of INVOICES_ROW or something else? A node has a parent, there is nothing like "preceding parent".

Comment: I need the count of all previous INVOICES_ROW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count all preceding INVOICES_ROW, use this:

```
count(preceding::INVOICES_ROW)
```

E.g., For the following XML:

```
<ROOT>
<INVOICES>
    <INVOICES_ROW/>
    <INVOICES_ROW/>
</INVOICES>
</ROOT>
```

This XSLT will produce output as "1":

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(ROOT/INVOICES/INVOICES_ROW[2]/preceding::INVOICES_ROW)"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think this is getting me on the right track, only I need to do this within a for-each loop. I can't specify that I want all previous from the second record.

Comment: Something like this: `count(preceding::INVOICES_ROW)` works but not for the first record. So I guess saying that I need all preceding rows was incorrect and instead I need all rows to the current point in transformation.

Comment: For the first INVOICES_ROW, count returns 0, as there won't be any preceding INVOICES_ROW to the first one.

Comment: How can I account for this? I tried using `<xsl:choose>     
       <xsl:when test="count(preceding::INVOICES_ROW) = 0)">
        <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::INVOICES_ROW)+1"/>
       </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>` but it fails on the `<xsl:when test="">` statement.

Comment: May be because it has an extra closing bracket :)

Comment: oh! good eye. Altova isn't the very best when it comes to pointing out errors.